# Extension degrees of fields of fractions and residue fields

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $A\subset B$ be integrally closed local domains, $K(A),K(B)$ be fields of fractions, and $k(A),k(B)$ be residue fields. How to prove $[K(B):K(A)]≥[k(B):k(A)]$?

This question is easy if $k(B)$ is generated by one element over $k(A)$, in particular, when $k(B)/k(A)$ is separable.

However, I don't know how to prove the general case. And I did not find this result in a book of commutative algebra.

Comment: Dear @Zhengyu, do you have any conditions on the domains $A$ and $B$ other than them being normal? If $A$ and $B$ are valuation domains, the result is standard and can be found in any text on valuation theory. If $B$ is integral over $A$ and the residue field extension is separable, you can find a more general result on any text on ramification theory in general (see for eg the first chapter of Ramification Theoretic Methods in Algebraic Geometry by Abhyankar).

Comment: @ArpanDutta I am still thinking about the conditions. For the moment, I believe these cases work. 1 the residue field extension is generated by one element, for example, separable. 2 $B$ is locally flat over $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ and $A$ is Noetherian. 3 $A$ is Noetherian and regular at $\mathfrak{p}$.